# Add programmatically created field to content type form

Tags: nodes, entities

I've programmatically created a content-type with 3 fields (in D8).

The fields are created but do not show up on node creation. If I go to the content-type form display, the fields are there, but I need to save this page to get the fields to show up on node creation.

The content-type and fields are created in yml-files and the Looks like this:

config/install/field.field.node.slideshow_slide.slide_weight.yml

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
config:
    - field.storage.node.slide_weight
    - node.type.slideshow_slide
module:
    - text
enforced:
    module:
        - custom
id: node.slideshow_slide.slide_weight
field_name: slide_weight
entity_type: node
bundle: slideshow_slide
label: 'Weight'
description: 'This slides weight'
required: false
translatable: false
default_value: 0
default_value_callback: ''
settings: { }
field_type: string
```

config/install/core.entity_form_display.node.slideshow_slide.default.yml

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
config:
    - field.field.node.slideshow_slide.slide_image
    - field.field.node.slideshow_slide.slide_link
    - field.field.node.slideshow_slide.slide_weight
    - node.type.slideshow_slide
module:
    - image
    - link
id: node.slideshow_slide.default
targetEntityType: node
bundle: slideshow_slide
mode: default
content:
slide_image:
    label: visible
    weight: 101
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
slide_link:
    label: visible
    weight: 100
    settings: { }
    third_party_settings: {  }
slide_weight:
    label: visible
    weight: 100
    settings: { }
    third_party_settings: {  }
links:
    weight: 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that it needed "type" for all the fields in the form_display.